# Gaussian convolution of data cube

Tags: python, gaussian, cube, astropy

I have a data cube called 'cube'. I need to convolve each 2d slice with a Gaussian kernel.

However using the following code this uses a normalised Gaussian kernel which dilutes the weaker pixels in each slice.

Is there a way to divide each pixel Gaussian by say 'max(Gaussian)' so that each pixel is convolved relative to the pixel strength?

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.convolution import convolve, Gaussian2DKernel

std = 2

gauss_kernel = Gaussian2DKernel(std)

for i in range(len(cube[:,0,0])):
        cube[i,:,:] = convolve(cube[i,:,:], gauss_kernel/np.max(gauss_kernel))
```

Comment: Wouldn't you get nearly the same effect by dividing your results by the slice, after the convolution?

Comment: I'm not sure really. What I believe is happening here is that for each element (or pixel) the resulting convolved gaussian which spreads across neighbouring elements is then normalised. Because of this, the higher valued elements are affected differently to the lower valued pixels. But what I need is for the elements to retain their original value but then spread blur out in a gaussian fashion into other elements. Dividing by the slice after convolution would just set each element to one wouldn't it?

Comment: The solution you've posted already illustrates how to convolve with a peak-normalized Gaussian.  The default is to convolve with an integral-normalized Gaussian.  What else do you want?   You might want to use http://spectral-cube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/smoothing.html#spatial-smoothing for the general use case of smoothing each channel in a cube

Answer (score 1):

The solution you've posted already illustrates how to convolve with a peak-normalized Gaussian.  From your comment, it sounds like you want your "peaks" to be unaffected by surrounding data points.  Strictly, that's not possible - convolution means *every* pixel gets "spread out".

However, you might be talking about *normalized convolution*, which astropy implements (see http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/convolution/index.html).  As long as the surrounding pixels are set to NAN, they will not contribute anything to their neighbors.  So if you have a sparsely populated array, with only a few pixels that you want to blur into surrounding "empty" pixels, just set the "empty" pixels to NaN.  See this example: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/convolution/index.html#using-astropy-s-convolution-to-replace-bad-data

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to kernels and convolutions on a high level, I believe.

Suppose you have some array of ones;

```
arr = np.ones((5,5))
```

And you also have some 2D convolution kernel

```
kernel = [[0,0,0],
          [0,1,0],
          [0,0,0]]
```

In this case, it's the identity kernel, so if you do `conv(arr,kernel)`, you should get back arr.

What if we changed the kernel to be a 1D box blur kernel?

```
kernel = [[0,1,0],
          [0,1,0],
          [0,1,0]]
```

You shouldn't expect to get a blurred version of `arr` back, i.e. an array that peaks at 1.  Consider element `(3,3)` - the old value was 1, and after convolution it will be `1*arr[3,2] + 1*arr[3,3] + 1*arr[3,4] = 3`.  If instead, `kernel` had 0.33 along its center column, you would get 1/3 of each element, and the value would remain 1.

This distinguishes a few classifications of convolution kernels - there are those that are *unnormalized* and their values are unconstrained, those that are *unit peak* and have maximum value of 1, and those that are *unit energy* which have a sum of 1.

The total energy (sum of all of the values) in your image will change with an unnormalized or unit peak kernel.  If you convolve with a unit energy kernel, the total energy in the image remains the same before and after.

To address your comment:

> Is there a way to divide each pixel Gaussian by say 'max(Gaussian)' so that each pixel is convolved relative to the pixel strength?

If the behavior you want is for bright things (stars) to be blurred more than dark things (background), that happens naturally.  Or, more specifically *high contrast* things are blurred more than low contrast things.  Imagine a camera, it could be a DSLR or your phone or anything else. If the blue, cloudless sky is out of focus, can you tell?  If a star is out of focus, can you tell?

If you want to somehow weight the value of pixels in the convolution, then you should duplicate your data and scale each pixel by an appropriate weight and convolve that modified data with your kernel.

Comment: Thanks that was really informative! I think you're right and that in a sense my lack of knowledge on the process was what was the problem and that the convolution will in fact work fine.